# Как можно отпимизировать два компонента с идентичной логикой но разными action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, react-hook

Как можно оптимизировать два компонента, чтобы вся логика содержалась в одном. Учитывая что берётся разный state и оттуда разные action. Хранилище отличается только селектором,и поэтому можно сделать кастомный хук. Но что делать с экшенами,ведь они относятся к разлиным редьюсерам.

```
function Movie() {

const dispatch = useDispatch();

const {items,films,page,pages,catItems} = useSelector(({movies})=>{
    return {
        items:movies.category,
        catItems:movies.category.activeItems,
        films:movies.items,
        page:movies.page,
        pages:movies.pages
    }
});
const handleAddCategory = (cat) => {
    dispatch(setActiveCategoryMovie(cat));
}
const handleRemoveCategory = (cat) => {
    dispatch(removeActiveCategoryMovie(cat))
}
const getItems = () => {
    dispatch(initializeFilter());
}

const getMoviesItems = (nextpage) => {
    dispatch(getMovie(catItems,nextpage));
}


useEffect(()=>{
    getMoviesItems()
},[catItems])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код нужно добавлять кодом а не скрином

Comment: Скриншотом я показал идентичность логики в двух компонентах.

Comment: Создай собственный хук. Свойства передавай не в конкретном виде а в образном. Один хук можно использовать множество раз, будет создаваться копия с разными данными. Вставь код в вопрос, попробую помочь) Сам только изучаю Реакт но суть вопроса ясна

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Название функиций и переменных взяты из потолка. Подобная структура поможет вам решить вопрос:

```
export function useCategories(nameCategories) {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const { items, films, page, pages, objectItems } = useSelector(({ [nameCategories]:object }) => {
        return {
            items: object.category,
            catItems: object.category.activeItems,
            films: object.items,
            page: object.page,
            pages: object.pages
        }
    });
    const handleAddCategory = (cat) => {
        dispatch(setActiveCategoryMovie(cat));
    }
    const handleRemoveCategory = (cat) => {
        dispatch(removeActiveCategoryMovie(cat))
    }
    const getItems = () => {
        dispatch(initializeFilter());
    }

    const getMoviesItems = (nextpage) => {
        dispatch(getMovie(objectItems, nextpage));
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        getMoviesItems()
    }, [objectItems])
    return { items, films, page, pages}
}
```

Comment: Спасибо) Это решает проблему взятия данных из хранилища. Но в случае, если я буду работать с "Tv" а не "Movies", то данный хук будет использовать не те action, которые изначально содержаться в компоненте Tv на скриншоте.

Comment: @Денис измени имя ```action``` на имя не конкретных элементов в хук передавай коллбек в return добавь свои стрелочные функции и импортирую.